# Fill empty rows with values of different non-empty row

Tags: r, row, is-empty

My question concern programming in R. My data set looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m03N2.jpg)

I'd like to fill empty (blanks not NA) rows from column `id_code` with appropriate values coming form column `distribution.type`.

My idea was used i.e `mutate` function `mutate(df$distribution.type [ifelse(df$id_code == "", df$distribution.type, df$id_code)])`
or something like this:

```
df$id_code[df$id_code == ""] <- df$distribution.type[df$id_code == ""]
```

and a plenty of another concepts, but they didn't work.
May I ask for your help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), based on the condition in 'i' i.e. rows where 'id_code' is `''` (`blank`), we assign (`:=`) the corresponding element of 'distribution.type.  It is assigning in place, so would be fast.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[id_code=='', id_code:= distribution.type]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a toy dataset:

```
df = data.frame('id_code'=c('','2','3',NA,''),'distribution.type'=c('A','B',NA,'D','E'),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Below is a subsetting solution (that specifically excludes rows with NAs).  See [Subsetting R data frame results in mysterious NA rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261619/subsetting-r-data-frame-results-in-mysterious-na-rows)

```
df$id_code[!is.na(df$id_code) & df$id_code == ""] <- df$distribution.type[!is.na(df$id_code) & df$id_code == ""]
```

Below is a solution using dplyr.  Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592577/2176211

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df,id_code = ifelse(id_code == "", distribution.type, id_code))
```